# Battery level indicator on Lenovo Ideapad 330 15ICH

Tags: lenovo, battery, ideapad

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2LTS with 4.18.0-20-generic kernel and I can't get it to display battery power level (for example through tweaks). The output of `upower -d`is:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ADP0
  native-path:          ADP0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Di 21 Mai 2019 18:31:08 CEST (2927 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Di 21 Mai 2019 18:31:08 CEST (2927 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       none
    icon-name:          'battery-missing-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.7
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: PowerOff
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with recent kernels (>=4.18 I think) recognizing the battery in the Lenovo Ideapad 330 15ICH. It has been fixed in kernel 5.0, so you can solve the problem in two ways AFAIK:

1) Installing Ubuntu 18.04.0 or 18.04.1 since they use kernel 4.15 which works fine with this computer. Only problem is the touchpad behaves a little bit uncontrolled sometimes.

2) Using a newer kernel like 5.0, everything works fine including the touchpad. I tried it in Debian 10.0 "Buster" installing the kernel from the experimental repository. Supposedly it should also work in Ubuntu 18.04 if you update the kernel >=5.0. Package linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge provides kernel  5.0.0.15.71

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=linux-generic-hwe&searchon=names